# Close button on adaptive popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uistoryboard

In a storyboard I have a root view controller with a button which triggers a 'Present as Popover' segue to a UINavigationController containing a UITableViewController.  I want the nav controller to be present on both iPhone and iPad.

On an iPad, this works great in a popover.

On an iPhone, I get the modal presentation, so now I need an additional bar button item to dismiss the modal view.  From watching the WWDC videos, I've attempted the following in the root view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)dismissPopover {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)presentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:(UIModalPresentationStyle)style {
    UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController *)controller.presentedViewController;
    UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPopover)];
    nvc.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bbi;
    return nvc;
}
```

I understand the `-presentationController:viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:` method should only get called when the UI is adaptive i.e. modal, however it doesn't get called at all, even when running as a modal on iPhone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to get it working.  I think my problem was that the `popoverPresentationController` property traverses up the view controller heirarchy until it finds a view controller with a `popoverPresentationController`, i.e. if I have a view controller inside a navigation controller inside a popover the view controller `popoverPresentationController` would go to the nav controller and use it's property.  For this to work, the view controller has to be a child of the navigation controller.  At all the points I was trying to use the `popoverPresentationController`, this was not the case, e.g `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`.  For some reason, `willMoveToParentViewController` is not called, even though `didMove` does get called.  So I have no idea how to reference `popoverPresentationController` in a vc inside a nav controller before the ppc delegate methods are called.

**However**, you can reference it in the presenting view controller in `prepareForSegue`, but you do need to explicitly tell it what presentation style to use.  Here's my code that works when placed in the presenting view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)dismiss {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationFullScreen; // required, otherwise delegate method below is never called.
}

- (UIViewController *)presentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:(UIModalPresentationStyle)style {
    // If you don't want a nav controller when it's a popover, don't use one in the storyboard and instead return a nav controller here
    UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)controller.presentedViewController;
    nc.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bbi;
    return controller.presentedViewController;
}
```

Comment: In the new multi tasking iOS9 world, it can switch back out from compact to regular width - so how to subsequently remove the Done button?

Comment: Does it automatically switch from the compact (modal) to regular (popover) presentation? If not, then I think this should still work fine. If it does transition, you can set or remove the bar button item in `- willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Comment: Nice solution. However, if you want to set up the Done button and the `UINavigationController` in your storyboard you can use the `navigationBarHidden` property to show the bar on compact environment and hide it by default in the storyboard.

Comment: @Scotty What did you figure out about Multitasking for this question?

Answer (score 15):

Here's the Swift version of Nick's correct answer for those who want a quick cut and paste.

Note: This is to create a popover on your iPad but a modal sheet with a close button on your iPhone.

In Xcode 6.3 storyboard, you hook up a view controller and designate the segue as a "Present as Popover"

The below code should go in the view controller that segues to the popover, not in the popover itself:

First you set up the popover delegate:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "myPopoverSegueName" {
        segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        return
    }
}
```

Then you add the delegate extension and create the navigation controller / close button on the fly:

```
extension myViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func presentationController(_ controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
        let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissPopover))
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
        nav.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnDone
        return nav
    }

    @objc private func dismissPopover() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: This works!! Thanks! On a separate note, one could this code instead if don't want to handle localization of the word Done manually :) let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "dismiss") if

Comment: Great answer, here is Swift 4:
Delegate:
```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "myPopoverSegueName") {
        segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Extension:
```
extension MyViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func presentationController(_ controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissPopover))
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
        nav.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        return nav
    }

}
```

Comment: Dismiss:
```
    @objc private func dismissPopover() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```
Sorry for the formatting. I can't spend more time on this now...

Answer (score 0):

I found that [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25349399/199360) doesn't correctly display a "done" button when in Compact mode (e.g. iPhone) but remain as popover in Regular mode (e.g. iPad).

The following code is the bare minimum to make this work – place these in the *presenting* view controller class.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}

- (UIViewController *)presentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:(UIModalPresentationStyle)style {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = controller.presentedViewController;
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UIPopoverPresentationController class]] && style == UIModalPresentationFullScreen) {
        UINavigationController* navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
        UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss:)];
        presentedViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbi;
        return navCtrl;
    }
    return presentedViewController;
}

-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Notice the three differences with the accepted answer:

- We don't need to override `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:`
- We check whether the presentation controller is the popover but requesting full-screen mode instead.
- We return a new navigation controller instance instead of (incorrectly) casting the presented view controller as a navigation controller.