# Show/hide dismiss button in a UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UINavigationController that I'm presenting in a popover using UIPopoverPresentationController.

The navigation controller must be presented when displayed in both popover and fullscreen mode (as the adaptive system so chooses.)

I have all this working.

The problem comes when I want to show/hide a dismiss button in the navigation controller depending on how it's being presented. I can't seem to determine whether I'm popover or fullscreen?

The WWDC stuff talks about returning a new navigation controller in presentationController:viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle - but that's no good in my case as my navigation controller may have had other controllers pushed onto it and so cannot simply be swapped out.

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Thanks

[UPDATE] So the presenting view controller gets traitCollectionDidChange: and if it's horizontal compact then I poke into the presentedViewController->childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem and set it to 'close'. But boy does this feel hacky.

[UPDATE2] So this link helps [Close button on adaptive popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275271/close-button-on-adaptive-popover) but the dismiss button is not then cleared when it switches back out to regular width.

Comment: When you present the popover, do you know whether it will be a popover or fullscreen? If you do, you could pass along a bool flag indicating if it's a popover or not, then in the `viewDidLoad` method of the presented controller, you know if the button should be hidden or not.

Comment: Hi Tim - thanks for that. Trouble is, it can change with the new multi tasking changes.